# How can capitalism be improved?

Tags: macroeconomics

Many people want to try socialism because of valid criticisms of capitalism. So, are there any good ideas on improving the problems of capitalism before we go down the path of socialism?

Comment: I feel like this question is both too broad and primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

19th Century American Economist [Henry George](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_George) argued that the real conflict wasn't between Labor and Capital, but rather between the owners of Land and everybody else.  Neoclassical reformulation of the [factors of production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factors_of_production) essentially merged Capital with Land, erasing the distinction and setting the stage for the current Socialism/Communism vs. Capitalism conflict we've had ever since.

[Georgists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgism) today support a return to the earlier model, which points to a middle way between the two extremes.  They argue that by taxing [economic rent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economic_rent) (the logical extension of payments made for the use of Land) governments can make infrastructure projects self-financing, eliminate the root causes of financial speculation (and the boom/bust cycles they trigger) and reduce inequality — all while maintaining (or increasing) the freedom of markets.